# Magento2: custom options import using CSV

Tags: magento2, custom-options, csv

I am working on CSV import to create a custom option for Products
I am facing the issue with the error

> Notice: Undefined index: type in
>   /var/www/html/home/vendor/magento/module-catalog-import-export/Model/Import/Product/Option.php
>   on line 1134

[image]

I already created Products (Configurable products)

I want to add a custom option to them I am importing my sample CSV link below
[csv link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1vpwxcpv4lsn9gQxGVi4Cxc9KQxZp9eaV)

Comment: what M2 version are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can first try to generate a csv file using the export feature and then use it for import? This way will make sure you have all fields.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue on a Magento 2.2.3 site that had been edited to use pipe character ( | ) as a multiple value separator instead of comma ( , ). I changed it back to comma to get around the issue.